# Tried with CSS selector and xpath but nothing is working for the button that i need to click

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to locate an element thats actually a button but every time it shows "Unable to locate such element."

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="details__selectItem"> 
    <a href="/product/lens?sku=4234_BLACKCRYSTAL" class="btn primary block" style="">
        Select Lens Type
    </a>
</div>
```

**I tried with following locators:**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Select Lens Type")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelectors("a.primary.block[href='/product/lens?sku=4234_BLACKCRYSTAL']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.className("details__selectItem")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Rozmeen Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: These method calls seem correct, although a little complicated due to the html not being selenium friendly. Maybe try findElements instead of singular, and see which elements are returned? I mostly prefer cssSelector myself. You could get all a.primary.block for instance and if more exist, see which ones it returns? When I have problems finding elements, it is most often because they are generated by some javascript, and are not available at the time I try to find them. Selenium have waiting functionality which lets you wait until the elements are loaded. I suspect that might be the error?

Comment: @KjetilNordin, this is the error trace: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"SelectLensType"}

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario, is that the element simply does not exist when you try to find it. Especially since you have tried four different selectors. This might happen when the page is not fully loaded when you try to locate the element. You can implement waiting functionality, which will wait a specified number of seconds, for the element to exist, be visible, or be clickable. I am not sure which language your Selenium is in, but here is a Java version:

```
int timeoutSeconds = 30;
By locator = By.id("element-id"); //use any 'By' here

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator)); 
driver.findElement(locator).click();
```

Alternatively, you can wait for clickable or visible, using this line instead of the second last in the example above:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
```

If you are using another language than Java, you will have to search the api of the specific language, to find the correct syntax. As far as I know, Selenium is not identical across languages, but I will expect this to be available in most of them.